# Eventlet and twilio api (Recursive Error)

Tags: twilio, gunicorn, eventlet

I am using a twilio api to send verification codes and everything is running well in the development server. When I switched to a production server using gunicorn and eventlet I keep on getting a Recursive Error when I try to send the verification codes. I tried using gevent and the and the verifcation codes were being send but without causing error 500 or Recursive Error. However I want to use eventlet and not gevent because my application is using socket io and gevent tends to be slow or doesnt hanlde the socket functions but eventlet is handling the socket functons well. How can I fix the Recursive Error.[Part of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEpsx.png)[The traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTvao.png)

I am expecting it the twilio api to send the verification codes without c=running into a Recursive error

Comment: Please don't drop screenshots of the code/error message but copy and paste them via markdown in the original question. This will make it easier for folks to answer.